# import Error: No Module named cropresize

Tags: python, django

I am new to python. I am working on some other's project but when i tried to run the code it give me the error said above. My all pages are working properly except those in which i had images. Is there any library required for the same??
Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: You need to show your code and provide the exact error message including the full traceback.

Answer (score 3):

you need to have `cropresize` package `http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cropresize/`  installed on your device.

If it is not there install it from the link

Do `easy_install cropresize` or `pip install cropresize`

Answer (score 1):

Just do [`easy_install cropresize`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cropresize/).

Answer (score 0):

cropresize package needs to be installed! First install pip(Ubuntu/Debian):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then install cropresize using pip:

```
pip install cropresize
```

Answer (score 0):

cropresize (all versions) depends on PIL.

Unfortunately, Pillow (installed) does not satisfy this dependency when using pip or easy_install :(